# Dragging is Fine with Chrome But Not in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/16/edit

When Im dragging in Chrome and FF its ok and dragging
But on IE (8) it wont drag and going into "Selection Mode"
How can i solve it ? ( Drag + Hide the Selected Text Mode )
**I don't want Draggable Plugin. I want to implement and understand.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According code you've provided, you are assigning the values right in `<script>` tag.
Use the `document.ready` event.

In my IE8 the shortcut `$` is not working. Try to differ the script add.

---

I've understand:

1. I've downloaded your code and run it locally - it works in IE.
2. I think IE simply forbids the scripts from other domain to run at the http://jsbin.com

I think such behaviour is because http://jsbin.com code seemed for IE as dangerous, and it simply forbids the outer sites links.

Comment: @Mid787 Look at second part of my answer - you must change the `jquery` script add for it works in IE. In your example IE just don't see the `$` object.

Comment: @Mid787 Updated the answer. I think the problem is in privacy of IE. It simply does not allow the jquery.

Comment: i have ie 8  , im not running script. im referencing it and use it locally. this is ok to do.  (if im doing alert on document.ready - its ok.) - so why its not dragging ?

Comment: @Mid787 I downloaded your code from jsbin.com and it worked on my machine in IE 8, after I allowed script executing.

Comment: what was the problem ? why ie shouts about it ? why ie and FF allow this ? can you explain ? thank you.